# Lines starting with '#' are throwing indexing error, even though I explicitly don't index those lines by exception. If I delete the # lines, works

Tags: python

I have some code that pulls in a CSV, converts it to text, then parses out various items based on delimiter and outputs an xlsx. Previously, as in last week, it could handle looking at a '#' as the first character of a given line, and would just pass over it when analyzing.

I changed nothing, was re running the same code, on the same input file, now if I have lines that start with '#' I get indexing errors. "IndexError: list index out of range":

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hale-j\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hale-j\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2924\1094649359.py", line 112, in myClick
    call1(name2)
  File "C:\Users\hale-j\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2924\1094649359.py", line 87, in call1
    dxrout.write('Name: ' +  newrec2.split(';')[0] + ';' + 'Description: ' + newrec2.split(';')[5] + ';' + 'Obj Type: ' + newrec2.split(';')[3] + ';'  + 'Obj Instance: ' + newrec2.split(';')[4] + ';'  + 'Units: ' + newrec2.split(';')[12] + '\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Even if I replace the # with something else(like two chars etc), it gives me the same indexing error.

If I delete the top 5 lines on the input file(which all start with a '#'), then it works like it did last week.

Here is the top of the input file:

[Can see the '#' lines here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xph7J.png)

```
r2 = newrec2.startswith('#')

if((r1==False) and (r2==False)):
    dxrout.write('Name: ' +  newrec2.split(';')[0] + ';' + 'Description: ' + newrec2.split(';')[5] +  '\n')
```

Considering I changed nothing, I have no idea what is going on. I cant understand why it wont just skip over the if logic if r2=False, as it did before.

Raw Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter.font as font
#

def call1(inputname):
    
    
        # 1. Open the CSV file in reading mode and the TXT file in writing mode
    with open(inputname + ".csv", 'r') as f_in, open(inputname + ".txt", 'w') as f_out:
        # 2. Read the CSV file and store in variable
        content = f_in.read()
        print(type(content))
        # 3. Write the content into the TXT file
        f_out.write(content)

    
    dxrout = open("DXR_EDE_Parse.txt","w")
    name = "Output.xlsx"

    replace_dict = {
            'Obj Type: 0' : 'Obj Type: Analog Input', 
            'Obj Type: 1' : 'Obj Type: Analog Output', 
            'Obj Type: 2' : 'Obj Type: Analog Value', 
            'Obj Type: 3' : 'Obj Type: Binary Input',
            'Obj Type: 4' : 'Obj Type: Binary Output', 
            'Obj Type: 5' : 'Obj Type: Binary Value', 
            'Obj Type: 6' : 'Obj Type: Calendar',
            'Obj Type: 7' : 'Obj Type: Command', 
            'Obj Type: 8' : 'Obj Type: Device', 
            'Obj Type: 9' : 'Obj Type: Event Enrollment', 
            'Obj Type: 10' : 'Obj Type: File', 
            'Obj Type: 11' : 'Obj Type: Group', 
            'Obj Type: 12' : 'Obj Type: Loop', 
            'Obj Type: 13' : 'Obj Type: Multistate Input', 
            'Obj Type: 14' : 'Obj Type: Multistate Output', 
            'Obj Type: 15' : 'Obj Type: Notification Class', 
            'Obj Type: 16' : 'Obj Type: Program', 
            'Obj Type: 17' : 'Obj Type: Schedule', 
            'Obj Type: 18' : 'Obj Type: Averaging', 
            'Obj Type: 19' : 'Obj Type: Multistate Value', 
            'Obj Type: 20' : 'Obj Type: Trend Log', 
            'Obj Type: 21' : 'Obj Type: Life Safety Point', 
            'Obj Type: 22' : 'Obj Type: Life Safety Zone', 
            'Obj Type: 23' : 'Obj Type: Accumulator', 
            'Obj Type: 24' : 'Obj Type: Pulse Converter' 
        }

    with open(inputname+".txt") as xx:


        for rec in xx:

            newrec2 =  rec.replace("'", ";" )
            
            
            r1 = newrec2.startswith('B_01')
            r2 = newrec2.startswith('#')
            r3 = newrec2.startswith('Infra')
            r4 = newrec2.startswith('PlnkBus')
            r5 = newrec2.startswith('PLNK')
            r6 = newrec2.startswith('AsView')
            r7 = newrec2.startswith('IO')
            r8 = newrec2.startswith('OnbMd')
            r10 = newrec2.startswith('APPLICATION')
            r11 = newrec2.startswith('Building')
            r12 = newrec2.startswith('# PROJECT_NAME')
            r13 = newrec2.startswith('# VERSION_OF_REFERENCEFILE')
            r14 = newrec2.startswith('# TIMESTAMP_OF_LAST_CHANGE')
            r15 = newrec2.startswith('# VERSION_OF_LAYOUT')
            r16 = newrec2.startswith('# mandatory')
            r17 = newrec2.startswith('# keyname')
            
            
            
            if(r10==True):    
                dxrout.write('Application Nr: ' +  newrec2.split(';')[6] + '\n')
                names = newrec2.split(';')[6] +'.xlsx'

            if((r1==False) and (r2==False) and (r3==False) and (r4==False) and (r5==False) and (r6==False) and (r7==False) and (r8==False) and (r11==False) and (r12==False) and (r13==False) and (r14==False) and (r15==False) and (r16==False) and (r17==False)):

                # delimit by ';' so read puts in own cell
                dxrout.write('Name: ' +  newrec2.split(';')[0] + ';' + 'Description: ' + newrec2.split(';')[5] + ';' + 'Obj Type: ' + newrec2.split(';')[3] + ';'  + 'Obj Instance: ' + newrec2.split(';')[4] + ';'  + 'Units: ' + newrec2.split(';')[12] + '\n')

            
        
    dxrout.close() 


    # read back the txt, apply the dictionary
    df = pd.read_csv("DXR_EDE_Parse.txt", sep=";", header=None)
    df2 = df.replace(replace_dict)
    df2.to_excel(names, engine = 'openpyxl',index=False)


root = Tk()
root.title("EDE File Parser")
entry = Entry(root, width=100, bd=5,) 
entry.insert(0, "Enter name of input text file here with no extension")
entry.pack()

def clearText():
   entry.delete(0, END)


def myClick():
    name2 = str(entry.get())
    call1(name2)
    myLabel = Label(root, text="Check output folder"+" for: "+ names)
    myLabel.pack()
    
    
# Format of GUI
myFont2 = font.Font(size=20)
myFont = font.Font(size=30)
myButton2 = Button(root, text="Clear", command=clearText, fg="black", bg="grey", padx=80,pady=20)
myButton2['font'] = myFont2
myButton2.pack()
myButton = Button(root, text="Click to Parse", command=myClick, fg="black", bg="green", padx=200,pady=100)
myButton['font'] = myFont
myButton.pack()
# pack

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace for the error, and the additional code necessary for someone to recreate the problem.

Comment: I don't think its the comment so much as `newrec2.split(';')` returning an a list < 6 items long, so `newrec2.split(';')[5]` is an index error. You could `print(repr(newrec2))` which would help show empty lines, to see if that's so.

Comment: I figured out how to get all the code in. So the input csv file, if the lines start with #, it throws the error, If I delete those lines in the csv, all is well in the world. Thank you for your analysis. I also added the full error message above. Thx.

Comment: As tdelaney said, this is likely an issue with your _input_. A complete [mre] would include a minimal input file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It could be something as simple as a space in front of a #. Or a blank line. That's why you want to trace the input - to see exactly which line fails. You should do the split once before write and that would be a good time to check for badness. `row = newrec2.split(";")` then `if len(row) < 13: print('fail', row)`.

Comment: I added a screen shot, apologies I am not super versed in this site, thank you for your patience and responses.

Comment: But really, the most practical thing is to trace the data your program gets. Something is a bit different than it seems. Luckily your code blows up in just the right place to know. If you print or save each line as you process, it'll crash, and that last line will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of code, paste in the text instead. Images are not text searchable.

Answer (score 0):

There was a strange string of characters coming in on the very first line before the '#' - so this was not there by exclusion and was trying to parse that line out. Thank you all for your help! [see capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCwRH.png)